# Removing lines in CSV file is adding extra lines

Tags: python, csv

I am working on a coding assignment where one of the requirements of the app is to be able to remove lines of interest in the CSV file. When I try to remove the line that is identified by the key (name), it not only removes the line but also adds multiple copies of my first line to my CSV file. I can't seem to figure out why it is adding these repetitive lines. Any help is appreciated.

For reference: attractions is a list of dictionaries that the csv file was copied into

The delete function is below

```
name = entername()

with open('boston.csv', 'r') as csv_read:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_read)
    for row in reader:
        attractions.append(row)
        for field in row:
            if field == name:
               attractions.remove(row)

with open('boston.csv', 'w') as csv_write:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_write)
    writer.writerows(attractions)
```

and my CSV file before looks like this:

```
Short Name,Name,Category,URL,Lat,Lon,Color
harvard,Harvard University,university,https://www.harvard.edu/,42.373032,-71.116661,green
mit,Massachusetts Institute of Technology,University,https://www.mit.edu/,42.360092,-71.094162,green
science,Museum of Science,Tourism,https://www.mos.org/,42.36932,-71.07151,green
children,Boston Children's Museum,Tourism,https://bostonchildrensmuseum.org/,42.3531,-71.04998,green
```

but results in this:

```
Short Name,Name,Category,URL,Lat,Lon,Color
Short Name,Name,Category,URL,Lat,Lon,Color
Short Name,Name,Category,URL,Lat,Lon,Color
Short Name,Name,Category,URL,Lat,Lon,Color
Short Name,Name,Category,URL,Lat,Lon,Color
harvard,Harvard University,university,https://www.harvard.edu/,42.373032,-71.116661,green
science,Museum of Science,Tourism,https://www.mos.org/,42.36932,-71.07151,green
children,Boston Children's Museum,Tourism,https://bostonchildrensmuseum.org/,42.3531,-71.04998,green
```

Comment: Is `attractions` a list of dicts or a list of lists? `for row in reader` will give lists when `reader` is a `csv.reader`. It needs to be `csv.DictReader` for `attractions` to be a list of dicts

Comment: if you keep working off the same file and rerunning your script, your header columns will keep being added over and over and over again each time you run your script/function. that seems to be the case since you are reading and writing to the same file

Comment: `for field in row:
            if field == name:` can be replaced by a single if statement: `if field in row:`

Comment: why append and then remove if a condition is met? just _don't_ append if your condition is met

Comment: I notice your code isn't initializing `attractions` here.  If I run your code by itself and set `attractions = []`, then it works perfectly.  BTW, rather than using `remove`, it would be smarter to scan the fields first and use that to decide whether to do the `append`.

Comment: Has any of the answers so far helped? Please accept an answer if it helped solve your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code and it appears to work.

I modified it to:

- hard-code the name (for debugging)
- print a message when a row is removed
- not overwrite the input file (VERY Helpful when debugging)

```py
import csv

name = 'Harvard University'

attractions = []
with open('boston.csv', 'r') as csv_read:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_read)
    for row in reader:
        attractions.append(row)
        for field in row:
            if field == name:
                print(f'{field} matches {name}, removing {row}')
                attractions.remove(row)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(attractions)
```

when I run that, I see this debug-print message:

```
Harvard University matches Harvard University, removing ['harvard', 'Harvard University', 'university', 'https://www.harvard.edu/', '42.373032', '-71.116661', 'green']
```

and this is my **output.csv**:

```
Short Name,Name,Category,URL,Lat,Lon,Color
mit,Massachusetts Institute of Technology,University,https://www.mit.edu/,42.360092,-71.094162,green
science,Museum of Science,Tourism,https://www.mos.org/,42.36932,-71.07151,green
children,Boston Children's Museum,Tourism,https://bostonchildrensmuseum.org/,42.3531,-71.04998,green
```

When I change name to `name = 'Tourism'`, which is valid with your logic (even if it isn't what you want/intend), it still does what you'd expect, remove the two rows where **Tourism** is in the **Category** field:

```py
...
name = 'Tourism'

attractions = []
...
```

```
Tourism matches Tourism, removing ['science', 'Museum of Science', 'Tourism', 'https://www.mos.org/', '42.36932', '-71.07151', 'green']
Tourism matches Tourism, removing ['children', "Boston Children's Museum", 'Tourism', 'https://bostonchildrensmuseum.org/', '42.3531', '-71.04998', 'green']
```

```
Short Name,Name,Category,URL,Lat,Lon,Color
harvard,Harvard University,university,https://www.harvard.edu/,42.373032,-71.116661,green
mit,Massachusetts Institute of Technology,University,https://www.mit.edu/,42.360092,-71.094162,green
```

All that said, I recommend not adding-then-removing when a certain condition is met. Instead, I favor adding if the *skip* condition isn't met:

```py
for row in reader:
    skip_row = False
    for field in row:
        if field == name:
            print(f'{field} matches {name}, skipping {row}')
            skip_row = True
            break  # stop searching fields

    if not skip_row:
        attractions.append(row)
```

And, if you only care about the **Name** field, this can be shortened and made even more straight-forward:

```py
name_idx = 1  # fields are 0-based, so your 2nd field is index 1
for row in reader:
    if row[name_idx] == name:
        print(f'Found {name}, skipping {row}')
        continue  # skip rest of this loop (the append), start with next row

    attractions.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a pure python [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) library which generates the code under the hood and provides lots of data processing primitives:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

name = entername()

table = Table.from_csv("boston.csv")  # pass header=True if it's there
columns = table.columns
table.filter(
    c.not_(
        c.or_(*(c.col(column_name) == name for column_name in columns))
        if len(columns) > 1
        else c.col(columns[0]) == name
    )
).into_csv("boston_output.csv")
```